# React Native unable to install app on iOS device with Diawi Link

Tags: ios

I shared Diawi link in ad hoc build. After installation on device, the app is not opening, but showing itunes with white logo. The device UDID is added to the provisioning profile. I am new to react native. so is there any build issue with react native?

Comment: Can you add the Diawi Link?

Comment: Just solved my problem doing zip .app file after build and change extension to .ipa it will work.Conventional archive technique is not work for me.